# Cannot change the image background in android using eclipse

Tags: android

I have a problem in changing the image background in Android using Eclipse.. I already replaced the previous image but then when the emulator run it always appears the replaced image.Pls help to solve this.Thanks

Comment: can u explain the issue? can't understand anything from ur que

Comment: delete application from the emulator and load again.

Comment: i already did that i deleted the application and load another emulator ..but then the same image will still appear on the background even that image is not already in the drawable folder.

Answer (score 1):

So what you are saying is that even after you replaced the images those images are still shown. Make sure that you replaced the previous images in all of the drawable folders. Because if you just replaced the drawable-hdi images but not the drawable-mdpi ones than if the emulator or device has a mdpi screen it will load the mdpi images from the drawable-mdpi folder thus showing the older images. So make sure you replaced all the images and not just in one folder.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `android:background="@drawable/backgroundmenu"` in your `Layout`  section in `XML activity`

But first, import an image called "backgroundmenu" in `drawable`.

Comment: i also added that code already and put the image in drawable but it still it doesnt work..is there anything that needs to be updated also?

Answer (score -1):

you need to clear your files in drawble folder in this location; ..\eclipse\workspaces\YourProjectName\bin\res\crunch\drawable

clear all files there, good luck!